# Corestriction of a full and faithful functor

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ be a full and faithful functor. Consider the corestriction $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow F(\mathcal{C})$ of $F$ to its image. Note that for $D\in F(\mathcal{C})$, we have $D=F(C)$ for some $C\in\mathcal{C}$: i.e. $D\cong F(C)$. This implies that the corestriction of $F$ to its image is an equivalence of categories.

Now, I don't understand the following:

> Replacing $F(\mathcal{C})$ by the full subcategory
> $\mathcal{C}'\subset\mathcal{D}$ generated by all the objects
> $D\in\mathcal{D}$ isomorphic to an object of the form $F(C)$, one
> still has an equivalence $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}'.$

I don't follow this characterization of $\mathcal{C}'$: specifically, I am not sure what a "subcategory generated by all the objects etc." means. I know that
$$\mathcal{C}'(D,D'):=\mathcal{D}(D,D')$$
for all $D,D'\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C}')$–but what are the object of $\mathcal{C}'$?

Can someone please give an explicit description of the full subcategory $\mathcal{C}'$?

**Edit:**

Is $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C}')$ merely $\{D\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal{D})\ |\ (\exists C\in\mathcal{C})( D\cong F(C)\}$? Then, why say "generated"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal{D}$ is a category then a subcategory $\mathcal{C}'$ of $\mathcal{D}$ is called *full* if for any two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal{C}'$ we have
$$
  \mathcal{C}'(X, Y) = \mathcal{D}(X, Y) \,.
$$
A full subcategory is uniquely determined by its class of objects.
Given any class of objects $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{D})$ we can therefore talk about the *full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ generated by $\mathcal{O}$*.
This is the unique subcategory $\mathcal{C}'$ of $\mathcal{D}$ with $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C'}) = \mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{C}'(X,Y) = \mathcal{D}(X,Y)$ for all objects $X, Y \in \mathcal{O}$.

In the given example we take
$$
  \mathcal{O}
  =
  \{
    D \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{D})
  \mid
    \text{there exists $C \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ with $D \cong F(C)$}
  \} \,.
$$
The resulting full subcategory $\mathcal{C}'$ of $\mathcal{D}$ is known as the *essential image* of $F$.

Regarding your edit:
I don’t think there is a particular reason why the verb “generated” is used here.
One could also use a different verb which describes the situation.
(I personally would talk about *the full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ whose class of objects is given by $\mathcal{O}$*.)

On a side note:
The image $F(\mathcal{C})$ won’t necessarily be a subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$.
So in general you won’t get an equivalence of categories between $\mathcal{C}$ and $F(\mathcal{C})$.
(But if $F(\mathcal{C})$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ then the corestriction of $F$ will indeed be such an equivalence of categories.)